# Is there a way to add a note to the iOS Health app?

Tags: health.app

**Is it possible to add a comment or note to the Health app?** I could see this ability as a useful way to interpret or supplement the data.

For example, if I'm sick for a few days, it could explain a change in my diet or weight. ("Today was Day 3 of flu symptoms, but I'm feeling better than yesterday.") Or, if I'm on a medication, I might want to make notes of any observations. ("I forgot to take my X pill last night; today, I have a headache.")

Comment: Be careful taking X pills - overuse of MDMA destroys the brains ability to replenish serotonin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Adding notes in Health.app

No, as of iOS 10.3.x you can't add comments to Health.app and its database.

---

### Alternative (3rd party apps)

If you want to enter any notes or observations you need to rely on a third party app to do so.

Ideally, this app should be able to export your notes in a non-proprietary format like XML. Not all apps (e.g. Pillow) with a notes feature allow you to do that. (Thanks @Mark)

---

### Alternative (use unused fields)

You may use unused Health.app fields to store your observations. Below are **special data types** that exceed the usual 'one value + one time stamp' values.

With graphs

- UV Index (**one number, start time, end time**)
- Sleep Analysis (three values, start time, end time)
- Blood Pressure (two numbers)

Without graphs

- Carvical Mucus Quality (five values)
- Menstruation (four values + one boolean (yes/no))
- Ovulation Test Result (three values)
- Sexual Activity (three values)

You could totally add 'UV Index' (value + duration) for headaches and 'Vitamin B12' for forgotten medications. Add them to Health.app's Today view using the 'Add to favorites' toggle and you're done.

Comment: And the third party apps don't always export that - e.g. Pillow

Comment: Thanks, @oa- . That's not the answer I wanted, but so be it. This issue has led me to ask a related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284576/72448

Answer (score 0):

It appears that as of iOS 16.3.1, you still can’t add notes in the Health app.